# HTML, CSS | Select previously removed arrow reveal

Tags: html, css, select

My issue is that I have to set all  the selected arrows on my website to be hidden by default with the following code.

```
   select::-ms-expand {
      //remove default down arrow in IE
      display: none;
   }

   select.form-control {
      -moz-appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
   }
```

Then I created a new select, which I don't want to carry this effect. I want this to appear as default. My question is what do I need to put in order to overwrite this.

```
  select.select-p-text::-ms-expand {
     //remove default down arrow in IE
     display:             ?;
  }

  select.select-p-text.form-control {
     -moz-appearance:     ?;
     -webkit-appearance:  ?;
     appearance:          ?;
  }
```

Thanks,

Kieran

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle so it's easier for people to understand?

Comment: @AndyHolmes he hid all this little arrows from select-form elements. Now he want to know how to show them again for one single element and what he has to write to accomplish this. Op has to look here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this code sir

```
   select:not(.selectClass)::-ms-expand {
      //remove default down arrow in IE
      display: none;    }

   select:not(.selectClass).form-control {
      -moz-appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;    }
```

this will make the class  called inside the **:not()** to inherit no css design